# DbSet Groups containing DbSets

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently using Entity Framework for an application i'm creating, but I'm quite fresh, so some things keep confusing me.

I have a simple question which I couldn't find an answer for.

Is it possible to store DbSets inside a DbSet? Say for example I want my users to be in groups. Each group should have their own sets of Articles, Customers, etc.

What I'm thinking is something like this:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group: DbContext
{
    public List<User> Members { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

I would then call for the articles like so:

```
context.Groups.Find(GetGroupIdOfLoggedInUser()).Articles.Find(id);
```

Is this possible, and if so, is it a good solution? Is there a better approach?

Regards,
Robin

Comment: Your entity objects (Group, Article etc.) should not inherit from DbContext and the properties just need to be simple collections, not DbSet objects.

Comment: Thanks! This worked as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Think of DbSet as your SQL table. So, you can not put a table inside a table.

Second: DavidG is perfectly right. You need to do the following:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public List<User> Members { get; set; }
    public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```